# Headers in a 2 by 2 layout

Tags: html, css

Hello all I am trying to style 4 h3 headers in a two by two layout with text under each h3 header I want it to look something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToC3H.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use bootstarp

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-6'>
    <h3> Heading </h3>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-6'>
    <h3> Heading </h3>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-6'>
    <h3> Heading </h3>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-6'>
    <h3> Heading </h3>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
  </div>
</div>
```